# Residual of the sum of i.i.d variables forms Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Let $Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables that only take positive integer values. For $i=1,2, \ldots,$ let $p_{i}:=\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{1}=i\right) .$ Suppose that $\mu:=\mathbb{E}\left[Y_{1}\right]<\infty .$ Define a sequence of random variables $X_{n}$ as follows:
$$
 X_{n}=\inf \left\{m \geq n: m=Y_{1}+\ldots+Y_{k} \text { for some } k \geq 0\right\}-n
 $$
For every $n=1,2, \ldots,$ further define a function
$$
 f(n):=\mathbb{P}\left(n=Y_{1}+\ldots+Y_{k} \text { for some } k \geq 0\right)
 $$

Prove that $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ forms a Markov chain and find the transition probabilities.

Find the necessary and sufficient condition for the limit $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)$ to exist. Please state the necessary and sufficient condition in terms of $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots$ and prove your statement.

When the limit $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)$ exists, find the limit. Express it in terms of $\mu$ and/or $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots$

I have no idea since the pdf of Y is not given, It is hard to get the distribution of X, Anyone any idea?Thanks

Comment: Start from $P(X_m = j | X_1= x_1,...,X_{m-2} = x_{m-2},X_{m-1} = k)$, use definitions and the iid nature, and see if you can eliminate the $X_1,...,X_{m-2}$ terms. You need to do this anyway to prove that $X_n$ is a Markov process.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks for your hint, would you please provide more details? Since the transition probabilities is needed.